# Has the word "magician" been used in the Harry Potter canon?

Tags: harry-potter

Although it's a valid word for a magic user, the word "*magician*" feels cheap to me, probably, because this is attached with those who displays trickery. Also, there are better words which I see everywhere in the canon: *wizard*, *witch*, *warlock*.

But I see lots of people using the words *magician*. Has this word ever been used in the canon (Canon meaning books, movies, interviews, Pottermore, Twitter, and official statements)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although the word "magician" doesn't appear in any of the Potter books, it does appear in a [Pottermore article](http://pottermorenewsfeed.tumblr.com/) about Vernon and Petunia Dursley:

> *Petunia did not want Lily as a bridesmaid, because she was tired of
>   being overshadowed; Lily was hurt. Vernon refused to speak to James at
>   the reception, but described him, within James’ earshot, as **‘some kind
>   of amateur magician’.***

This obviously could be considered an insult within the wizarding world.

Note that the word "*illusionist*" is also conspicuously absent.

---

Interestingly, Alan Rickman describes his character, Snape as a "black Magician" in an [interview with Unreel](http://web.archive.org/web/20070707073420/http://www.unreel.co.uk/features/featurealanrickman.cfm)

> *I think at heart Snape is basically quite an insecure person, he's
>   always longing to be something else that people will really respect
>   like a **black magician** not just a school master. That's why he envies
>   the more popular and successful boys like Harry. He does have his
>   positive side though even though Harry's a thorn in his side he
>   doesn't let it worry him too much.*

Comment: In the interests of answering [the recent dupe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186680/31394) as well as the question above: is the word "magician" ever used in-universe by non-Muggles?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - It hasn't appeared in **any** of the books, said by muggles, wizards or the narrator.