# In Harry Potter, do magical people refer to themselves as "magicians"?

Tags: harry-potter, names

As the question title states, **do people in the HP universe refer to wizards and witches as "magicians"**?

From [etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/magician)

> **magician (n.)**
>   late 14c., from Old French magiciien "magician, sorcerer," from magique

Magic + Sorcery = Witches and Wizards

If it's not used, is there an in-universe reason why?

Comment: Per the dupe, the word itself appears nowhere in any of the books and only in a single vanishing reference on Pottermore.